# Calling Google Sheets API from Zoho Deluge function: The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects

Tags: google-sheets-api, zoho

I am trying to read a Google Sheet by calling the Sheets API from a Zoho CRM Deluge function. I have created a project in the Google Developer Console and input the Key into the 'invokeurl' parameters. When I try to execute the call, I get the error:

> "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects."

I tried creating an OAuth client ID, but the Google Sheets API only accepts Access Tokens. I admit, I don't know how to programmatically get an access token without giving consent with a pop up (not an option here).

I tried creating an access token using the Google OAuth Playground, but got the same "different projects" error.

I read on a Zoho support article that adding the headers:

```
{"X-HTTP-Method-Override":"PATCH","Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

help call Google APIs. When I did that, I get a different error:

> "The requested URL /v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheet ID]/values/[range]?key=[my key] was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

I have no other ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here is the relevant portion of the Zoho function:

```
params = 
{
    "key":myKey
};
sheet = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + id + "/values/" + range
    type :GET
    parameters:params
    connection:"to_google_sheets"
    headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override":"PATCH","Content-Type":"application/json"}
];
```

Comment: For example, when the URL including the API key is requested by the curl command, what result will you get?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that since I had made a "connection" to the Google Sheets API in the Zoho CRM, I didn't need to pass the Key.

Removing that line made it work just fine.